# Configuration to change the landing page on AEM Dispatcher

Tags: configuration, aem, dispatcher

Is there any configuration we need to provide on AEM dispatcher settings for redirecting the domain to landing page?

For example,

user enters `mydomain.com`, the page should redirect to `www.mydomain.com/index.jsp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the following configuration in httpd.conf file for the requirement.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^/$ /index.jsp [R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Redirects cannot be done within dispatcher (except directing to 404 via filters).

To do that you have to use the vhosts section of httpd (per domain) and mod_rewrite plugin, best combine it with properly done http mappings inside CQ